# How does RxJava doOnError and onErrorReturn work?

Tags: java, system.reactive, rx-java

I made these unit tests, and the outcome is not what I expected at all:

```
// This one outputs "subscribe.onError" 
@Test
public void observable_doOnError_subscribingToError() throws InterruptedException {
    Observable<String> obs = getErrorProducingObservable();
    obs.doOnError(throwable -> System.out.println("doOnError"));
    obs.subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate()).observeOn(Schedulers.immediate()).subscribe(
        s -> {},
        error -> System.out.println("subscribe.onError")
    );
    Thread.sleep(300);
}

// This one outputs "subscribe.onError" 
@Test
public void observable_onErrorReturn() throws InterruptedException {
    Observable<String> obs = getErrorProducingObservable();
    obs.onErrorReturn(throwable -> "Yeah I got this");
    obs.subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate()).observeOn(Schedulers.immediate()).subscribe(
        s -> System.out.println("got: " + s),
        error -> System.out.println("subscribe.onError")
    );
    Thread.sleep(300);
}

private Observable<String> getErrorProducingObservable()  {
    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        subscriber.onError(new RuntimeException("Somebody set up us the bomb"));
    });
}
```

So both output "subscribe.onError" - neither `doOnError` nor `onErrorReturn` seems to be called.

`doOnError`is documented as:

> Modifies the source Observable so that it invokes an action if it calls onError.

I'm not sure how to intepret that, but I expected either "doOnError" to be output or "doOnError" followed by "subscribe.onError".

`onErrorReturn` is documented as :

> Instructs an Observable to emit an item (returned by a specified function) rather than invoking onError if it encounters an error.

Hence I was expecting "got: Yeah I got this" as output from the latter test.

What gives?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Both `doOnError` and `onErrorReturn` returns a new `Observable` with the changed behaviour. I agree that the documentation of them may be a little misleading. Modify your tests like this to get the expected behaviour:

```
// This one outputs "subscribe.onError" 
@Test
public void observable_doOnError_subscribingToError() throws InterruptedException {
    Observable<String> obs = 
        getErrorProducingObservable()
            .doOnError(throwable -> System.out.println("doOnError"));

    obs.subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate()).observeOn(Schedulers.immediate()).subscribe(
        s -> {},
        error -> System.out.println("subscribe.onError")
    );
    Thread.sleep(300);
}

// This one outputs "subscribe.onError" 
@Test
public void observable_onErrorReturn() throws InterruptedException {
    Observable<String> obs = 
        getErrorProducingObservable()
            .onErrorReturn(throwable -> "Yeah I got this");

    obs.subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate()).observeOn(Schedulers.immediate()).subscribe(
        s -> System.out.println("got: " + s),
        error -> System.out.println("subscribe.onError")
    );
    Thread.sleep(300);
}

private Observable<String> getErrorProducingObservable()  {
    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        subscriber.onError(new RuntimeException("Somebody set up us the bomb"));
    });
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks. Now it works as expected, and I learned that `doOnError` does not change the behaviour for the subscribers  - you just add a second error listener.